Flutter DraggableScrollableSheet with FlutterMap
I have a DraggableScrollableSheet with FlutterMap. I want that the Map widget adjusts its height to the remaining height of the draggable sheet.
Here is my widget tree
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(children: [
          CommonWidgets.createRouteBadge(route, routeTypes?[route?.type]?.name,
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 18),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
            CommonWidgets.formatTripHeadsign(trip!.tripHeadsign),
            softWrap: true,
          ))
        ]),
        actions: (widget.stopId != null) ? [IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showStopRouteTimetable(route!.id!, widget.stopId!);
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        )] : [],
      ),

      body: Stack(
        children: [
          OsmMapWidget<StopWithStopTime>(
            useMarkerClustering: false,
            showCurrentLocation: true,
            initialZoom: 15,
            getTripStopMarkers(),
            getTripShape()?.let((that) => [that]) ?? getTripShapeFromStopPoints() ?.let((that) => [that]) ?? [],
            (stop) {
              return InkWell(child: createTripStopWidget(stop.stop), onTap: () {
                selectStop(stop.stop.id);
                mapController?.center(Location(stop.stop.lat!, stop.stop.lon!), null, null);
              },);
            },
            (mapController) {
              this.mapController = mapController;
            },
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: isLoading,
            child: const LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: null,
            ),
          ),



          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            controller: sheetController,
            maxChildSize: 0.5,
            minChildSize: 0.2,
            expand: true,
            shouldCloseOnMinExtent: true,
            snap: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context, scrollController) {
              return Container(
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  ),
                ),
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  slivers: [
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                          height: 4,
                          width: 40,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    stopTimes?.isNotEmpty == true ?
                      SliverList.builder(
                        itemCount: stopTimes?.length ?? 0,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final stopTimeUpdate = stopTimes?[index];
                          final stop = allStops?[stopTimeUpdate?.stopId];
                          final isSelected = selectedStopId == stop?.id;
                          final isVehicleThere = false;//tripUpdate?.
                          return TripStopItem(
                            index: index,
                            totalCount: stopTimes?.length ?? 0,
                            stop: stop!,
                            stopTimeUpdate: stopTimeUpdate!,
                            isSelected: isSelected,
                            isVehicleThere: isVehicleThere,
                            itemClickListener: (stopTime, stop) {
                              selectStop(stop.id);
                              mapController?.center(Location(stop.lat!, stop.lon!), null, null);
                            },);
                        },
                      ) : SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: Container(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                            child: CommonWidgets.createEmptyState(
                                isLoading ? AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading : AppLocalizations.of(context)!.no_departures,
                                Icons.directions_bus, isLoading)))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
  }



